# Expresss.js static() not working with subdirectories that are more than one folder deep (it seems)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vue.js

I have the following folder structure for my Express.js app (on the left), and I have `static()` being used on line 19 in the middle. You can see that I have a path defined for `'./client'`, and I used `path.join()` just in case (nothing changes if I take that out or leave it).

You can see in my network log on the right that all the other assets I'm referencing in my app are served just fine, *except* the `components` sub-directory under the `js` folder, even though `js/main.js` loads.

Why doesn't `static()` see or work with more than one subdirectory deep? If I move my `Invoices.js` file up to `js`, it works, but I wanted to keep all my Vue.js components in a folder.

[image: express.js static() subdirectory problem]

Here's also where I'm referencing the `Invoices.js` file in my Vue.js app, if that helps:

[image: main.js definition]

Comment: Can you try [caseSensitive](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) option, seems could be the culprit

Comment: Does your vue app successfully import `Invoices.js`?

Comment: @JackYu No, it does not, because the request to load it returns a 404, as shown in the network log above

Comment: @uke Already tried that, no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

So, somehow, I had a space at the end of my `components` folder name. I figured this out after staring at the screen for a minute, and then just thought to myself, "I wonder if I'm looking at a typo or something and I'm just too dumb to see it". So, I just copied the exact way I typed `components` in my code, and pasted that value as the folder name. Once I did that, everything worked and loaded as expected.

Tl;dr - Make sure you type things correctly when naming folders.

It's a Friday -_-